# Stationary points of $(x+y+z)^3 - 3(x+y+z)-24xyz +a^3$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima, stationary-point

The [solution in the book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=tzdDDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA325&dq=show%20that%20f(x%2Cy%2Cz)%3D(x%2By%2Bz)%5E3%20-%203(x%2By%2Bz)-24xyz%2Ba%5E3&pg=PA325#v=onepage&q=show%20that%20f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z)%5E3%20-%203(x+y+z)-24xyz+a%5E3&f=false) says that there are 2 stationary points $(1,1,1)$  and $(-1,-1,-1) $.

Why $(0,1,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$,$(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$ are not the stationary points ?

Comment: WA says no stationary points are found

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - I have edited the link to the book. Please check it again.

Comment: Also Mathematica has found neither maximum nor minimum

Comment: I am not really concerned with maximum/minimum. Just want to know all the stationary points.

Comment: The book is wrong about "Therefore, either $x = 0, \, y = 0, \, z = 0$ or $x = y = z$." You can verify that setting just two of the variables to zero is enough to satisfy all three equations. The stationary points are $(-1, 0, 0), \, (1, 0, 0), \, (-1, -1, -1), \, (1, 1, 1)$ and all possible permutations (8 stationary points in total).

Answer (score 0):

You must solve the system
$$3(x+y+z)^2-3-24yz=0$$
$$3(x+y+z)^2-3-24xz=0$$
$$3(x+y+z)^2-3-24yx=0$$

Comment: These equations are also satisfied by $(0,1,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$,$(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$ ,apart from $(1,1,1)$ and $(-1,-1,-1)$ . But the book says only $(1,1,1)$ and $(-1,-1,-1)$ are stationary points.

Comment: What is definition of stationory point the book is following? @Anuj ?

Comment: I think there's only 1  definition of stationary points- points where first derivatives vanish.

Comment: It seems to me the book is following the defintion of stationary points to be either maximum or minimum. Because rest of the points are saddle points.